# Difference between assignment to object variable and class variable/attribute

Tags: java

Does it make no difference whether I assign the values directly to the object via the constructor (within the class) (this.xy = xx) or whether I assign it to the class variable (xy = xx).

I understood it to mean that the class itself was just a kind of construction plan. I thought that if you create an object from a class (Class class = new Class (xx)) and this calls the constructor, that at that point in time the object has already been created and now only the values are assigned for the first time. According to this understanding, it should actually not be possible to assign the values to the class and its attributes, but rather I would have to assign it directly to the object. But apparently it works anyway. Maybe someone can explain to me what I didn't quite understand.

Comment: When you have a field `xy` and you assign it `xy=xx` is actually a shorthand notation for `this.xy=xx`.

Comment: Also, when somebody says "class variable" they probably mean a 'static' variable. Maybe you can make a more concrete example to illustrate your question?